# How do we change the TLS version of Azure IoT Hub which is already created and deployed?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I see that we can enable TLS version only during `IoT Hub` creation in `Azure` portal.How do we change this version POST creation? we have already deployed in PRODUCTION and now we need to change it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. There is no option in the portal for this, and it can't be achieved through ARM either. Trying it with ARM will result in the following error:

```
MinTlsVersion cannot be set when IotHub is in Active state
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-tls-support?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#tls-12-enforcement-available-in-select-regions) confirms that this field is read-only and can't be changed.

Comment: I also see that Microsoft yet to support TLS 1.3

Comment: Correct, you could add a feature request for it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/fcb810f7-f824-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)

Comment: Until Microsoft supports us, what should be our security controls to save from 1.2 vulnerabilities?

Comment: That's probably a separate question. Maybe one best asked on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/25494/azure-iot-hub.html?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034), there's usually Microsoft people who can help you with that.

Comment: Could you share the ARM json which you tried to change the TLS version? which lead to the above mentioned error.

Comment: I don't have it any more, but I probably used [Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.devices/iothubs?pivots=deployment-language-bicep?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#iothubproperties) and changed the `minTlsVersion` and tried to deploy again.